# Different style for odd/even pages' page number

Tags: google-docs

I've created a document, with the first page not counted and other pages have a page number in the header. Then since I want to make it like a book, I should have an odd page number at top left and even page number at top right. I know it can be done in `Word` by selecting different style for odd and even (something familiar to), but how can I do this in `Google Docs`, I've googled and none of the result tells me, everybody is talking solution for `Word`.

So how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that this is a year old, but I found this problem recently and I have found only one way to achieve it, but it's just a workaround.

The way I got this was creating a local document with LibreOffice Writer and saving it using docx format, configuring the odd/even footers there (here's how to do this: https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Alternating_Page_Styles_on_Odd_and_Even_Pages) and then uploading the file to Google Drive. Then, you can edit the document in Google Docs and the app will keep the format (I don't understand why they don't have this feature if they support that formatting).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Even/odd page footers are supported now in Google Docs.

Answer (score 0):

Double-click the header, click "options", click "Header Format", and then choose "Different Odd & Even". Then select the even-numbered header and locate the "Right align" button (or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>). This is the way I did it for my own book, which I'm currently writing (in my case, I used footers instead of headers, but it should work either way).