# Insert section break odd/even page

Tags: google-docs, formatting

In Microsoft Word, when I insert a section break, I can tell it to start the next page on an odd page or even page:

[image]

Is there a way to do this in Google Docs?

Comment: Related: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/20258/88163 , https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/113680/88163